# How to search a specific part of a JSON object and add to an already existing object

Tags: java, android, json

I'm new to using JSONs and I'm having a bit of difficulty. I am using the Kitsu API and parsing the JSON I get when I login. When I parse my json the image below pops up, but inside the 1 object array I want to get the large url in the avatar object inside of the attributes object and I don't know how.[The beginning of the JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEPBW.png), [The middle of the JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPYUj.png), [The end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqxXt.png). Lastly, I want to know how to edit the slug part of the JSON, if you don't know that's cool the main thing is getting the avatar url.

[Picture of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udEET.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try this...

```
JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONArray myArray = myObject.getJSONArray("data");
JSONObject obj = myArray.getJSONObject(0);
String id = obj.getString("id");
String type = obj.getString("type");

//change the lines bellow
JSONObject attributes = obj.getJSONObject("attributes");
JSONObject avatar = attributes.getJSONObject("avatar");
String large = avatar.getString("large");
```

Comment: Okay, I tried that and it's just not taking data, I'm also semi new to stack overflow so it'll be a bit before I add a picture of what I'm getting.

Comment: JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            JSONArray myArray = myObject.getJSONArray("data");
            JSONObject obj = myArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String id = obj.getString("id");
            String type = obj.getString("type");
             JSONObject attributes = new JSONObject("attributes");
            String avatar = jsonStr.data[0].attributes.avatar.large;

Comment: I'm sorry, but due to stack overflow's character limit I can't put in the whole method.

Comment: But yeah only data is red, while everything else if fine.

Comment: There is a picture at the top of the thread that shows my error.

Comment: Try `myObject.data[0].attributes.avatar.large`

Comment: It still isn't working. When I press alt +  enter the only option it gives me is to rename data, because it can't resolve it.

Comment: @jmorg85 I changed my answer. Take a look in the new code a put there.